# iOS Core Data - Updating Multiple records

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite, ios6, xcode4.5

I've scoured and still haven't found anything that quite works. Either the question/answer is too old or it simply hasn't worked for me.  This is my first attempt at "my own" app.  As it seems a right of passage, I'm making a checklist app.  Here's what I'm looking for:

My Data Store contains 4 attributes: `name, category, isChecked, isActive` (more will surely follow as I expand)

When my View Controller initially loads, the `NSFetchedResultsController` has an `NSPredicate` that only retrieves the records whose attribute `isActive` is YES (or `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES`).  It then takes those records and displays them into the appropriate cells for the user.  When a user clicks on a cell, the Data Store updates and changes the `isChecked` attribute accordingly.  Everything works good to this point.

What I need to do now is to be able to remove the items (1 or more) from the list.  Specifically, I need it to update the Data Store attributes `isChecked` and `isActive` to NO only if it's current `isChecked` attribute is YES. (I'm not looking to delete the record from the data store as they will be used to build up the database for the users future use.)

I've used, among other things:

```
[[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] 
   setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] 
   forKey:@"isChecked"];
```

This does actually work, it removes the checkmark(s) and updates the store accordingly.  Problem is, not only am I making another request to the data store for the `isActive` items, it also searches the entire "Active List" that was fetched and sets each of their `isChecked` attributes to NO.  This may not be too big of an issue for small lists, but as the list(s) expand this can be an issue.

The other problem is, if I add:

```
[[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] 
   setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] 
   forKey:@"isActive"];
```

It sets ALL of my list items to NO (as well as a second data store request within the same method.)

So my question is: How can I get through the list, find only the items that are checked and update only those records (set both the isChecked && isActive attributes = NO) whose `isChecked` attribute is YES rather than working through the entire list?

I've tried creating a separate fetchedResultsController specifically for this buttons action, and it did work (that is to say, it didn't crash) but the debugger popped out a rather large 'Serious Application Error'.  I won't post the error message as it's long and most likely irrelevant to any solution.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance and please be gentle :-].

**EDIT**

I have tried using a `for` loop, `for (NSString *item in fetchedResultsController)` but I get the error `...may not respond to 'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count'`

It seems a loop of sorts is what's needed here, but again, nothing I can find is relevant or it's outdated.  Again, thanks for any assistance.

**Edit 2**

Here is the original error I got when I ran a second separate fetchRequestController for this button/method:

`An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 3 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)`

Comment: You should try using `NSBatchUpdateRequest`. Take a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66635329/1703291

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop over the fetchedObjects collection and change the managed objects. After changing them you'll need to reload your list (I guess you use a tableview).

I don't know what your classes are named, but in general you can just loop over the collection of managed objects and change them. Remember that you need to save your managed object context if you want to keep these changes for when the app closes.

```
NSArray* myCollection = [[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects];
for(ActiveListData *managedObject in myCollection)
{
    if(managedObject != nil && managedObject.isChecked)
    {
        managedObject.isChecked = NO;
        managedObject.isActive = NO;
    }
}
```

If you want to do the check on all object in the database you'll need a new method in your NSFetchedResultsController that has a predicate checking on isChecked and then loops over and edits the result collection.

You might want to post your error code as we could be able to point out what you did wrong.

Edit: If you're not familiar with using Core Data the apple documentation provides a lot of information: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html

Comment: I tried this, using `ActiveListData` which is the name of my NSManaged subclass but got the error `Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjecsDidChangeNotification. no object at index 3 in section at index 0 with userInfo (null).  Check my edit up above for the original error I got for creating a seperate "fetchRequestController" for this.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked into the apple dev docs and there is a TON of info but it's a whole lot of theory to go through to find an actual example (if there ever is an example).  At least on here, I can put what I need into a context and get a relatively straight answer.  I read the dev docs best I can but it's not always the easiest place for an answer

Comment: What does fetchedObjects return? Is it an NSArray?

Comment: Yes I believe that's what that function is for, pull each object out of the NSFerchedResultsController so you can iterate through them

Comment: Just keep fetchedObjects in an NSArray and loop over the array whenever you need to change them. Make sure you cast them to ActiveListData.

Comment: That's what I tried using your example, cycling through a for loop, casting it to my ActiveListData managed subclass. I got the hard crash stated above.

Comment: Just edited my code to add nil check. You're sure your database data is correct?

Comment: Thanks @ggfela for your help. I added my code and an explanation of it to this question so anyone coming in the future can get a clearer idea of what was going on with this.  Think that was part of the problem of the other answers I found on the subject was that they weren't really explained well.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ggfela for his answer.  The processes of his answer were spot on.  Here is the actual code I put into my button/method, in hopes of it helping someone else in the future:

```
NSArray *moc = [[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects];

for  (ActiveListData *item in moc) {
    if (item != nil && item.isChecked.boolValue == 1) {
        item.isChecked = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        item.isActive = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    }
}

// Call to Data Store to update the list
NSError *error;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error);
    return;
```

**Explanation:**

Load the contents of the result from calling the `fetchedResultsController` method into a temporary variable named `moc`

Use a `for` loop to cycle through the array of `moc`.  `ActiveListData` is the NSManagedObject subclass that I created for my Core Data and is the proper place to insert the separated values/attributes from the data store.  From there, it's pretty simple, I ensure that `item` is not `nil` AND that the item's attribute is the value I need.

**NOTE**

Core Data does not store the bool values YES and NO but rather 1 and 0, respectively but when you call or compare the values, you simply can not compare the value of `item.isChecked` because it is being passed back to you as a bool not as an integer.  You can not simply compare `item.isChecked == YES` either since the `@property` of `isChecked` is an `NSNumber`.  So, in the case of the `if` I put `item.isChecked.boolValue` as this will give me the representing integer for it's bool value, in this case I have it check for a 1 (YES). (Sorry if my explanation is wrong and/or confusing, but this is how I understand it and is the only way this code works.)

Then, setting the new values of these attributes is like you would expect when setting any other variable.  The only "tricky" difference with this is that the NSManagedObject subclass sets the `@property` of the `isChecked` and `isActive` to an `NSNumber` (as mentioned earlier) so in order to send the proper values back to Core Data you use the method `numberWithBool` of the `NSNumber` class.

And just in case anyone gets confused by my `FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error)` call this is simply a macro that was defined inside the `Prefix.pch` file to handle my errors from the managedObjectContext.  You can use any (or none) error handling you choose.

Thanks again @ggfela for your help!!  If anyone else has any other suggestions on how this code should be applied, then please let me know!

Comment: Good job, I totally forgot CoreData uses NSNumbers instead of booleans.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSBatchUpdateRequest to update multiple records

Examples:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/new-in-core-data-and-ios-8-batch-updating/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-core-data-and-batch-updates--cms-22164